# Error cloning certificates repo, please make sure you have read access to the repository you want to use

Tags: ios

I am using fastflane to process a CI, this is my `Fastfile`:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    if is_ci
      create_keychain(
        name: ENV['MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME'],
        password: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"],
        default_keychain: true,
        unlock: true,
        timeout: 3600,
        lock_when_sleeps: false
      )
    end

    match(
      type: "appstore",
      readonly: is_ci,
      keychain_name: ENV['MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME'],
      keychain_password: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"]
    )

    build_app(
        workspace: "Runner.xcworkspace",
        scheme: "Runner",
        export_method: "app-store"
    )

    upload_to_testflight
  end
end
```

but when I execute the script in Github Actions:

```
- name: Setup SSH Keys and known_hosts for fastlane match
      run: |
        SSH_PATH="$HOME/.ssh"
        mkdir -p "$SSH_PATH"
        touch "$SSH_PATH/known_hosts"
        echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" > "$SSH_PATH/id_rsa"
        chmod 700 "$SSH_PATH"
        ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
        chmod 600 "$SSH_PATH/known_hosts"
        chmod 600 "$SSH_PATH/id_rsa"
        eval $(ssh-agent)
        ssh-add "$SSH_PATH/id_rsa"
      env:
        PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
    - name: Deploy to TestFlight
      run: |
        cd ./ios && bundle exec fastlane beta
      env:
        TEAM_ID: ${{ secrets.TEAM_ID }}
        ITC_TEAM_ID: ${{ secrets.ITC_TEAM_ID }}
        FASTLANE_USER: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_USER }}
        FASTLANE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_PASSWORD }}
        FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD }}
        FASTLANE_SESSION: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_SESSION }}
        MATCH_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MATCH_PASSWORD }}
        MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME: ${{ secrets.MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME }}
        MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}
        DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS: ${{ secrets.DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS }}
```

tells me:

```
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|                             Summary for match 2.170.0                              |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| type                           | appstore                                          |
| readonly                       | true                                              |
| generate_apple_certs           | true                                              |
| skip_provisioning_profiles     | false                                             |
| app_identifier                 | ["com.earth.dolphin"]                             |
| username                       | ***                                  |
| team_id                        | ***                                        |
| storage_mode                   | git                                               |
| git_url                        | https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/certificate.git |
| git_branch                     | master                                            |
| shallow_clone                  | false                                             |
| clone_branch_directly          | false                                             |
| force                          | false                                             |
| force_for_new_devices          | false                                             |
| skip_confirmation              | false                                             |
| skip_docs                      | false                                             |
| platform                       | ios                                               |
| derive_catalyst_app_identifier | false                                             |
| fail_on_name_taken             | false                                             |
| skip_certificate_matching      | false                                             |
| skip_set_partition_list        | false                                             |
| verbose                        | false                                             |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+

[03:49:49]: Cloning remote git repo...
[03:49:49]: If cloning the repo takes too long, you can use the `clone_branch_directly` option in match.

Cloning into '/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/d20201206-6165-yfbvor'...
[!] Error cloning certificates git repo, please make sure you have access to the repository - see instructions above
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
[03:49:49]: Exit status: 128
[03:49:49]: Error cloning certificates repo, please make sure you have read access to the repository you want to use
[03:49:49]: Run the following command manually to make sure you're properly authenticated:
[03:49:49]: $ git clone https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/certificate.git /var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/d20201206-6165-yfbvor
```

Access to the private repo encount a problem, and what should I do to make it work?